# Settings files via grunt.config

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to set the files option in grunt config dynamically.

This works:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    mocha_casperjs: {
        options: options,
        files: {
            src: ['test.js'] 
        }
    }
});
```

And I'm trying to reproduce it like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('run_tests', function() {
    grunt.config('options', options);
    grunt.config('files', { src: ['test.js'] });
    grunt.task.run('mocha_casperjs');
});
```

But the files attribute is not set. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please, read carefully about [`grunt.config`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config) API.

`grunt.config.get(taskName)` returns config object for specified task. It performs just key's lookup in the root config object.
`grunt.config.set(taskName, newValue)` works the same way.

So, to set new files for *mocha_casperjs* you need to do it like this:

```
var mochaCasperjsConfig = grunt.config.get('mocha_casperjs');
mochaCasperjsConfig.files = { src: ['test.js'] };

grunt.config.set('mocha_casperjs', mochaCasperjsConfig);
```